# Date format in strong typed ListView's EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my markup for EditItemTemplate section of a ListView, i want to render short dates format:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaArribo" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", BindItem.FechaArribo ) %>'>
```

Which produce the runtime exception :

> BindItem does not exist in the current context

Without format expression it works but with the not desired time component. Advices?

Comment: try `Eval("FechaArribo")`

Comment: @Smeegs, this is a strong typed control so i wanted to use model binding feature

Comment: Try using `Item` instead of `BindItem`, you may not be able to use the BindItem if it's not the only object inside of the server tags.  Similarly to using `Eval` instead of `Bind`

Comment: @Smeegs with Item it will work, but then values entered are discharged and not reflected in the entity. BTW, what you mean with "not the only object inside of the server tags"?

Comment: You can't bind formatted text because it's no longer a two-way bind.  The object being bound needs to have a getter and a setter, but string.format is just a method with a string output.

Comment: @Smeegs I get you. So, it is not possible to format that way and use model binding feature?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: @Smeegs,  ok so i go with Bind("FechaArribo","{0:d}") by the moment. Just to be fair, please post that as the answer to accept it cause you move me to that direction when you suggested me to use Eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Bind("FechaArribo","{0:d}")`, although it will technically be a breach of strong-typing.

Answer (score 1):

At last after struggling for two days I get a solution for this two way model binding issue for formatted field value. Just remove the "" or '' after the property text of the TextBox. It works for me like a charm!! But if you use the TextMode property of the TextBox to Date, remove it. Cause, it will not display a value from server or DB. If you want to use a datepicker or calendar, you can simple add an AJAX CalendarExtender control to pick a date from calendar.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaArribo" runat="server" Text=<%# Bind("FechaArribo", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>/>
```

Comment: The OP wants it strongly typed using BindItem.FechaArribo.